# Partial decoherence of a general one-photon state

Tags: quantum-operation, information-theory, decoherence, quantum-optics, depolarizing-channel

Let $\rho_1$ be the pure one-photon state described by the ket
$$|\psi_1\rangle = \int dk\ A(k)a^\dagger(k)|0\rangle$$
for a complex amplitude function $A(x)$ and an empty ket $|0\rangle$. This state is obviously coherent, since non-diagonal terms with amplitudes $A(k)A^*(k')$ contribute to the density matrix.

The main tools to describe loss of coherence that I know of are the depolarizing and the dephasing channels. However, most treatments deal only with their application to a qubit state. How does one describe partial decoherence of such a state (preferably, in a calculation-friendly way)?

Comment: Note crosspost https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/798982/291677